# Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 (with JDK 1.7.0_45).

I've downloaded and uncompressed Eclipse Kepler for Java EE Developers.

The software menus are messed up. I didn't notice similar problems in other software.

When I click any menu in Eclipse, the drop-down seems to be "cut". Sometimes the drop-down shows, but the options are invisible.

I tried Eclipse Indigo, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: I have the same problem but with Eclipse CDT, Also noticed then if I run eclipse using sudo the menus are fine.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

## How To solve Eclipse menu issues in Ubuntu 13.10

### (Stable way, until someone fixes the bug)

This method takes for granted that you already have your **eclipse.desktop** file (or that you can alternatively create a new one from scratch). Otherwise, you can momentarily take a look at the "fast way" below.

1. Open your **eclipse.desktop** file:

   ```
    sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

(If you can't find it in this path, try in `~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`. Otherwise, you could have to find yours using `locate` command).

2. Replace the `Exec=` line with this:

   ```
    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
   ```

Where "eclipse" is the path to your eclipse executable. In this case it's just "eclipse" since there's a symlink in `/usr/bin` folder.

**NOTE:** If you can't find your **eclipse.desktop** file, you can simply create one from scratch in the above path, and fill it with these lines:

```
    [Desktop Entry] 
    Type=Application 
    Name=Eclipse 
    Icon=eclipse 
    Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse 
    Terminal=false 
    Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

3. Save the file.

Now you can run Eclipse from its icon as usual.

### (Fast but repetitive way)

If you haven't got any **eclipse.desktop** file and you don't want to create it at the moment, you can simply run Eclipse with this command:

```
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
```

where "eclipse" is the path to your `eclipse` executable. Note that this is just the fast way to run Eclipse once. If you don't want to remember this command and use it every time you have to run Eclipse, follow the "stable way" above.

Or you can make an alias out of it

```
alias eclipse = 'UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse'
```

and the command eclipse will work fine.

---

**Sources:**

- [Keenformatics - How To show Eclipse menu in Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander](https://www.keenformatics.com/how-to-solve-dell-laptops-fan-issues-in-ubuntu/) (my blog)
- [Ubuntu documentation - EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)
- [Eclipse menus doesn't show up in Saucy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1208019)

Comment: This was a working fix for me but it has broken again and this doesn't solve it anymore

Comment: @user1128171 It still works for me.

Comment: A short explanation (or a link) on how to create the eclipse.desktop file would come handy.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - running `gedit` will create the file anyway ;-)

Comment: @LuísdeSousa as wilf wrote, simply running `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` will create the eclipse.desktop file.

Comment: I already learnt how to create text files in Linux. Now what I need to know is how to create a functioning .desktop file.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa a functioning .desktop file is createad just like every other text file: just name it **eclipse.desktop**. If you create it with the right content, it will work. There's no particular procedure other than creating it in the right directory.

Comment: Kurt, what is exactly the *right content*?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa the right content is written in the post above, at step 2.

Comment: Note the short way does require a POSIX shell.

Comment: Works flawlessly for me too! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: make sure to remove any extra spaces from the lines when creating the `Eclipse.desktop`

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 - Not working...

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't have this issue on Eclipse Juno using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, my laziest fix is

1. Open a **Gnome Terminal** *(CTRL+ALT+T Default Shortcut)*
2. Issue `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 eclipse`.

Works for me.

Comment: this is the only solution that works for me. adding `Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse` to my eclipse.desktop file doesn't solve the problem for me on Ubuntu 13.10 :-(

Comment: Didnt work in 14.04

Comment: @thefourtheye perhaps the workaround is really just for version 13.10

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. How to make this permanent ?

Answer (score 6):

In my case there were two versions of the file in /usr/share/applications:

```
eclipse.desktop
Eclipse.desktop
```

Either delete one of them, or change the Exec line in both of them as described above.
The third version of the file is in the home folder:

```
~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop
```

You can either delete this last one or change the **Exec** line in this one too.

All you have to do is change the **Exec** line as follows:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /path/to/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to ~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer adding the `~/.local` path.

Comment: This was it! I was wondering why mt changes in the desktop file wasn't taking effect, it was all because of the .local version of the desktop file...

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit a file called eclipse.desktop to include the MENUPROXY option.

- Depending on your install, this location will vary. To find it, type `sudo find / -name eclipse.desktop`.
- Once you find the location, open up the file in your favorite editor. For me, this is vim, so I type `sudo vim /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` (Note that your location may be different, see the first step.
- When in the file, look for a line that looks something like this-> `Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse`. (Note that yours may just have the "eclipse" in there without the full path).
- After finding that line, comment it out. Then add this line: `Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /opt/eclipse/eclipse` (Edit as needed. If your install did not have the full path, or if it had a different path, adjust here). Note the space after MENUPROXY= . This is important.
  ` Start up Eclipse and enjoy menus on the top again.

Comment: I don't have a file like that, the terminal didn't return any results.

Comment: @JeroenBollen You can create that file and fill it with the content I wrote in my post above (**How To solve Eclipse menu issues in Ubuntu 13.10**).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181641&p=12819998#post12819998
The menu of Eclipse do not show in Unity Global Menu. Works with me.

Comment: Worked for me too but require executing from command line, also with CDT I eclipse would not recognize c++ and claims no available editor but that was fixed by deleting .metadata and restarting.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the file didn't exist,

I had to create it in `~/.local/share/applications`

just create `eclipse.desktop` containing

```
Version=4.3.0
Name=Eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= path=/home/abali/apps/eclipse/eclipse Icon=/home/abali/apps/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;
```

Don't forget to do

```
source eclipse.desktop
```

, then open eclipse and it just works.

Comment: What? `source eclipse.desktop`? **Don't do this**, it's completely unnecessary and may have unwanted effects.