# Gajim: Can't access submenus in top menu bar

Tags: unity, 13.10

I just installed Gajim 0.15.4 from Ubuntu repository on Ubuntu 13.10.

[image]

**Advanced**, as far as I know, is supposed to be a sub-menu. Clicking on it does nothing.
What can I try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the only workaround i've found is to disable the global menu for gajim as described for eclipse here :

https://askubuntu.com/a/371447

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19526584

So just replace Exec= line content by this :

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= gajim
```

Gajim will stop to use globalmenu and you will get your submenus back ;)