# How to create a Menu item for Eclipse in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: unity, eclipse, menu

I upgraded Eclipse yesterday to version 4.3 and was faced with the [missing menus bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-doesnt-show). To get the menus back one has to start Eclipse in a different way, thus I tried to create a new item in the Main Menu.

For some reason the item is not stored by the Main Menu, I get no error messages when I click the OK button in the new item dialogue, but nothing changes in the Application group.

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

**Update I**: [user wilf tells me](https://askubuntu.com/a/407713/177437) to add a file named `eclipse.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` but this has not created an new item in the Main Menu:

[image]

**Update II**: Here's how my `eclipse.dektop` file looks like:

```
$ ls -la /usr/share/applications/e*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3083 May 11  2012 /usr/share/applications/easytag.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  167 Jan 25 17:02 /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  921 Oct 31 20:30 /usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  856 Jun 29  2013 /usr/share/applications/eog.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  894 Oct  8 23:21 /usr/share/applications/evince.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  873 Oct  8 23:21 /usr/share/applications/evince-previewer.desktop

$ cat /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Icon=eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=/usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Beyond this, is there any other way to get the Eclipse icon showing up in the dash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write in your question that your .desktop file contains this:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=/usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse
```

but it should contain something like this:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse
```

Note the space between `=` and `/`. The `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` variable needs to be unset for eclipse to work correctly. You are setting it to eclipse and not launching any applications.

Though I don't know if this solves your problem, since I think this shouldn't cause the icon not showing up, just it won't do anything when clicked.

---

UPDATE: So the above haven't made eclipse to show up, here is one more thing you can try:

Put the .desktop file in the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory, this is where you can store per-user .desktop files, maybe unity will detect it from there. If it does, don't forget that the .desktop files in that directory is only available to the user in whose home directory the .desktop file is located, so if you have more users just copy the .desktop file to every users `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

Also note that for the desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications/` it is needed to logout to show up in the dash. (I don't know why, but it is so on my side.) So if you put there the .desktop file don't forget to logout/logback.

Comment: Hi falconer, I changed the .desktop file as you suggest, but I still have no Eclipse item in the Dash or Alacarte.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa There are some things which are not clear for me from you question: Are you using Unity? (I guess you are because of the unity tag.) When you say *"the item is not stored by the Main Menu"*, what Main Menu are you referring to? The Dash or the Launcher bar on the left? Or you are just referring to that picture from alacarte in your screenshot? If you are just referring to that screenshot, then you are looking at the wrong place there, since you created the .desktop file with "Categories=Development;IDE;Java;", it will be shown under *programming*, not under *other*.

Comment: Hi again falconer, I am using Unity. The screen shots where taken at an earlier stage, before the `.desktop` file had the Categories section. When I say "Main Menu" I refer to Alacarte, since that is the name by which it is shown in the Dash (this is rather confusing). The Eclipse item is not present anywhere at the moment in Alacarte, neither in *Others*, nor in *Programming*, nor anywhere else. It isn't shown in the Dash either, weather I search for it or going through the sections in *Applications*.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Okay, thanks for the clarification. It is strange that is is nowhere shown. One more thing you can try is to put the `.desktop` file in the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory, this is where you can store per-user .desktop files, maybe unity will detect it from there. If it does, don't forget that the .desktop files in that directory is only available to the user in whose home directory the .desktop file is located, so if you have more users just copy the .desktop file to every users `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa It is also possible that you already have an eclipse.desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/` in which case that .desktop file takes precedence over the `/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` desktop file, and the latter is not shown anywhere. This can be a cause, but that would mean someone put an eclipse.desktop file into `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Also note that for the desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications/` it is needed to logout to show up in the dash. I don't know why, but it is so on my side. So if you put there the .desktop file don't forget to logout/logback.

Comment: Hi again falconer. There was no `eclipse.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` so I just copied there the one in `/usr/share/applications` and log out. After logging in Eclipse is now finally showing up in the Dash and in Alacarte. This is mighty weird but indeed answers my question. Please add these comments to your answer so I can accept it. Any idea why the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` is being ignored? Thanks.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa I don't know why it doesn't show up from there. I put a .desktop file in my `/usr/share/applications` dir with the same contents as yours in the question, and it showed up immediately. You may try to test whether if you rename that .desktop file from eclipse.desktop to e.g. aaabbb.desktop make it show up. My only clue is this, that there is a naming conflict somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Locate the path of your executable file with `which` command:

```
which eclipse
```

Create a `.desktop` file:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Open the file with a text editor of your choice, with root privileges, say with `nano` as:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

and copy the following to the file and save the work: <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-doesnt-show/371447#371447)</sup>

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Icon=eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=path_to_eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

*(where path_to_eclipse should be replaced by the path output of the `which` command used above. Or replace path_to_eclipse by eclipse and create a symbolic link to executable file pointed by the `which` command.)* For example in your case, since the executable is `/usr/share/eclipse.kepler/eclipse` the `.desktop` file would look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Icon=eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=/usr/share/eclipse.kepler/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Now eclipse should appear in the menu.

---

To create a symbolic link use:

```
sudo ln -s -T source_file target_file
```

where you should replace *source_file* with the absolute path of `eclipse` and place the target_file i.e. the link in `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo ln -s -T path_to_eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Comment: This seems to be the same [method provided by wilf](http://askubuntu.com/a/407713/177437), that didn't work.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa, did you specify the absolute path of `eclipse` in the `.desktop` file's `Exec` entry?.. how do you start the application?.. what output did you get `which eclipse` command?

Comment: ..did you get it solved @LuísdeSousa ? ..please share if you did.

Comment: At this stage I'm only able to start Eclipse from the command line. `which eclipse` returns void. I have it installed in `/usr/share`.

Comment: is the executable `/usr/share/eclipse` or something else ?

Comment: The executable is `/usr/share/eclipse.kepler/eclipse`.

Comment: ..and even including this path in .desktop file didn't work, or else?

Comment: Apparently the `eclipse.desktop` file is being ignored by Alacarte, or whatever software that manages the menus.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are referring to [Alacarte](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/). For some reason, that does not always save the changes.

I would do as [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/371447/178596) answer suggests, but remember, even if you have no `.desktop` file for Eclipse, that this should do it for you:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

[image]

And here is the properties window in case you don't believe me:

[image]

Comment: There is no `eclipse.desktop` file in my system. I thank the information but it is not really answering my question. Is this a bug with Alacarte? Can it be fixed?

Comment: But `gedit` command will create it! Thats all you need to do! ;-)

Comment: `sudo touch /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` has not created a new entry in the Main Menu. I then copied in [the contents proposed in the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/371447/177437), but still no new item appears in the Main Menu. Please stick to the question.

Comment: It should create a new entry, it will be under 'Other' - I'll add a picture...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method https://askubuntu.com/a/80016/240859 to create launcher activator (you can then move it anywhere you like) but modify `~/.local/share/applications/opt_eclipse.desktop` a little bit to make it look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=<path to icon.xmp like /opt/eclipse/icon.xpm>
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0  <path to eclipse like /opt/eclipse/eclipse>
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Add `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`part. Don't forget modify paths in Icon and Exec.