# Create drop down menu in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, menu

I have problem to get the drop down menu in my Eclipse.

I have reviewed the solution in other Q&A threads, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407708/how-to-create-a-menu-item-for-eclipse-in-ubuntu-13-10) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show/371447#371447) (Being the most 2 helpful one). After following the instruction, I am able to get Eclipse with drop down menu, but only when I access it with nautilus (root access). Without root access, I am not able to get the drop down menu at all.

I download my Eclipse from the website, and the path to eclipse is /usr/local/.

Here how my eclipse.desktop look like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= usr/local/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= usr/local/eclipse
```

with

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /usr/local/eclipse
```

(there's a `/` before `usr`).