# Can't open menus in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and successfully installed the latest version of Eclipse, but when I  run it, I can't open menus like file, Edit, Run, etc.

Why is this and what I should do to solve this problem?

Comment: ... *minues*, *minus*... What exactly do you want to say?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question may already be answered here: [Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show](http://askubuntu.com/q/361040). Is this the case? If that question doesn't answer your question, [edit] your question to add what you have tried and how they didn't work. If the question *is* the same, your's will be closed as a [duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates) to keep the site clean and organised.

Comment: add more details.add what you tried,what it did(or didn't do),add images and be specific.