# Eclipse missing menus when starting from CLI

Tags: command-line, eclipse

I'm a new Ubuntu user. Over the past weeks I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and the latest Eclipse Kepler IDE, plus the workbench plugin from Libre Ada for the Gnat system. I'm using Ubuntu either locally on the machine it is installed or through an X11 terminal from my Windows machine.

Today, after installing all the latest updates Ubuntu reported to me I noticed a strange behavior. When I start Eclipse locally through the command line, none of the top menus show up, Files, Edit, Project, whatever they all just show a thin black bar and nothing else. I also have an Eclipse icon in the startup bar on the left of the desktop and when I use that, Eclipse shows all menus.

When I start Eclipse through the remote X11 terminal session using the command line there, the menus show up as well. Of course they look differently there using another display manager I assume.

Also, when I close Eclipse I get a whole bunch of error messages on the console. I include a section here as a sample because the list is really long

```
[PRJ_NORMALIZE] 1/3 Normalize: imported=empty (18:27:37.120)
[PRJ_NORMALIZE] 2/4 Done normalizing empty (18:27:37.120)
[ENTITIES.ASSERT] 1/14 Reset entities database (18:27:37.138)
GetBuffer file=/home/patric/workspace/Common_Library/Simple_TCP_Server/src/main.adb returned from editor buffer 105 bytes
GetBuffer file=/home/patric/workspace/Common_Library/Simple_TCP_Server/src/main.adb returned from editor buffer 105 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-rbtgbo.ads returned from file 6858 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-rbtgbo.ads returned from file 6858 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-lfwtio.ads returned from file 1216 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-lfwtio.ads returned from file 1216 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-suenco.adb returned from file 12914 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-suenco.adb returned from file 12914 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-stache.ads returned from file 4468 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-stache.ads returned from file 4468 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-pack15.adb returned from file 4846 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-pack15.adb returned from file 4846 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/g-awk.ads returned from file 26770 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/g-awk.ads returned from file 26770 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-chtgbk.ads returned from file 5123 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-chtgbk.ads returned from file 5123 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-stunau.adb returned from file 3043 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-stunau.adb returned from file 3043 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-chahan.adb returned from file 18829 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-chahan.adb returned from file 18829 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/g-sestin.ads returned from file 3241 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/g-sestin.ads returned from file 3241 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-vallld.adb returned from file 3493 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-vallld.adb returned from file 3493 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-pack25.adb returned from file 4848 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-pack25.adb returned from file 4848 bytes

.......

GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-textio.ads returned from file 18917 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/a-textio.ads returned from file 18917 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-stchop.ads returned from file 4648 bytes
GetBuffer file=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/rts-native/adainclude/s-stchop.ads returned from file 4648 bytes
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 1/29 Trace-Creating target 'Check Syntax' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 2/30 Trace-Creating target 'Check Semantic' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 3/31 Trace-Creating target 'Compile File' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 4/32 Trace-Creating target 'Build Main' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 5/33 Trace-Creating target 'Build All' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 6/34 Trace-Creating target 'Compile All Sources' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 7/35 Trace-Creating target 'Build <current file>' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 8/36 Trace-Creating target 'Clean All' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 9/37 Trace-Creating target 'Clean Root' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 10/38 Trace-Creating target 'Clean Project' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 11/39 Trace-Creating target 'Run Main' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 12/40 Trace-Creating target 'Custom...' (18:27:48.875)
[BUILD_CONFIGURATIONS] 13/41 Trace-Creating target 'Custom Build...' (18:27:48.876)
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please did you even search? It's all over the internet but here you go.

[Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show)

Comment: Yes I did search but nothing showed up, I still appreciate the link though