# Eclipse fail to start in a clean workspace

Tags: unity, java, eclipse, workspaces

I'm having a problem starting any version of eclipse in any kind of workspace (brand new or with data already).

The problem started when I upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, and tried to relaunch the eclipse (Springsource tool suite actually) that I've being using all the time.

I've tried cleaning the .metadata from the workspace, a clean workspace, the last STS available to download in the flavours of eclipse 3,8 and 4.2 and different JVMs. The results are always the same... when I start eclipse, after its shown the splash screen followed by workspace dialogue and the interface, it would freeze and close without any error message.

This is the console log that I get:

```
➜  sts-3.5.0.RELEASE  ./STS -clean -refresh -debug -consolelog -clearPersistedState
Start VM: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/STS
-name STS
--launcher.library /home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 44b8014
-product org.springsource.sts.ide
-clean
-refresh
-debug
-consolelog
-clearPersistedState
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar 
Install location:
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20130319-1000.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.fx.osgi_0.9.0.201401250701.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/plugins/
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.200.I20130319-1000.jar
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.osgi_0.9.0.201401250701.jar
Splash location:
    /home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/org.springsource.sts_3.5.0.201404011851-RELEASE/splash.bmp
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Debug options:
    file:/home/esteban/springsource/sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 54
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting application: 9910
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/esteban/Documents/workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.4.1.20140328-1905.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: eclipse.consoleLog=true
!SESSION 2014-04-26 13:24:39.103 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.5.0.201404011851-RELEASE-e38
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide -refresh -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide -clean -refresh -debug -consolelog -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-04-26 13:24:55.424
!MESSAGE Unable to find view with id: com.springsource.sts.roo.ui.rooShellView, when creating perspective com.springsource.sts.ide.perspective

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-04-26 13:25:03.208
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2014-04-26 13:25:03.209
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'AUTOGEN:::org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.actionSet/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.relaunch.action':
HandlerActivation(commandId=AUTOGEN:::org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.actionSet/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.relaunch.action,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.ui.launch.StopProcessPullDownToolbarDelegate),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.actionSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1a70ad13),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1a70ad13)),sourcePriority=16640)
HandlerActivation(commandId=AUTOGEN:::org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.actionSet/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.relaunch.action,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.ui.launch.RelaunchProcessPullDownToolbarDelegate),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.launch.actionSet,org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1a70ad13),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@1a70ad13)),sourcePriority=16640)
```

That is all. It closes and I don't know what else can I do. Do you have any idea of what seems to be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally realize what was the problem. It was related to the bug with the menu that was reported repeatedly, eg: [Eclipse menus are cut off or don't show](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show)

I've followed the instructions on that post, augmented the PermGem in the STS.ini and presto! it all started to work well again :)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 afresh.
Installed Oracle Java JDK 1.8
Installed STS (Spring tool suite) and started. Thrice it has frozen and had to resort to Alt + Sys Rq + REISUB.
Installed updates. By default, swap was disabled. So, enabled 2Gb swap. Checked your question and used your command line invocation.
STS started normally. It freezes for some time when you start it, but returns back to normal working.

Comment: I've tried what you suggest, but the result was the same. BUT the same version of STS with the same workspace it's working fine in gnome shell, therefore I think that the problem might be related to unity and maybe to the bug in the menu