# Menu bar in Eclipse - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, java, eclipse, menu

I started using Ubuntu again. I installed my daily IDE for Java development in Ubuntu.Then I created a `eclipse.desktop` file in `/home/username/.local/share/applications` directory and dragged it to my launcher in order for the ease of launching.

Then I faced the issue of menu bar not enabling issue. As discussed in following answer, I changed the `.desktop` file too.

https://askubuntu.com/a/371447/419134

However, it did not help me. Then I followed the following answer

https://askubuntu.com/a/389991/419134

It helped me. But it should be done again and again.

So I changed my `eclipse.desktop` file combining above 2 answers. This is how it looks now.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/home/username/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse/icon.xpm
#Exec=/home/username/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse/eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY = 0 /home/username/eclipse/jee-neon/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```

Now, When I drag the `.desktop` file to the launcher and click on it, Eclipse does not open. instead, it shows the indication that it has been clicked on, but does not start. 
The commented out line is the one which works correctly.

How can I correct this in order to run eclipse with the menu bar every time I open eclipse using the icon on the launcher?

Comment: Hope you have not actually typed "env  UBUNTU_MENUPROXY = 0" ??
 (note the spaces around = )

Comment: there are two spaces, one in left  one in right to the = mark